# Algorithm: Grouping children in groups of four

Tags: algorithm

I need the name of an algorithm for the following: 
There are 24 children. They play in groups of four. Each child should play with all other children. A child can only play with 3 other children at a time, and has to play with 23 other children, and since `23/3` leaves a remainder, some children will have to play more than once. Also, what if the were 12 girls and 12 boys, and each group should always consist of two girls and two boys?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: This is hardly a programming problem, more like a combinatorial problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it's a programming problem when you have to write a program that solves it ;-) but otherwise you are probably right.

Comment: This could (but I think not) be lreated to **lottery wheeling**; also (more likely) to **tournament scheduling**, perhaps [bridge](http://www.durangobill.com/BridgeCyclicSolutions.html) or perhaps you need more general than that

Comment: @Jonners, how is asking for the name of an existing algorithm akin to "plz send me teh codez'? I'm merely asking for help identifying the algorithm, not asking anyone to write my code.

Comment: @AakashM, thanks... I will look into some tournament scheduling algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By searching for material on **tournament scheduling** I found http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/tournaments/individual-pairs/ip-pure_24.html which has these properties:

> This is an individual pairs for 24 players.
>
> Each player partners each of the others exactly once.
>
> Each player opposes each of the others exactly twice.
>
> No set of three players meet together more than once

I haven't looked further for stuff that would meet your two-kinds-of-people criterion, but hopefully this will give you useful search terms. Various card-playing communities seem to have spent a lot of time thinking about these things.